# nodejs-dialogflow library returning TypeError: dialogflow.SessionsClient is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a script that takes input from the user, runs it through Dialogflow, then returns it back to the user. The platform I am taking input from only supports Node.js. I am hosting the bot through glitch.com, but I don't think that's what's causing the issue. I wanted to check on here before I submit a bug report onto the [GitHub repo.](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow)

```js
var bot = 'the platform i use to accept inputs and send outputs'

bot.on("message", async message => {

  console.log(message.content); // Log chat to console for debugging/testing

  if (message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) === 0) { // Message starts with your prefix

    let msg = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length); // slice of the prefix on the message

    let args = msg.split(" "); // break the message into part by spaces

    let cmd = args[0].toLowerCase(); // set the first word as the command in lowercase just in case

    args.shift(); // delete the first word from the args


    // You can find your project ID in your Dialogflow agent settings
    const projectId = process.env.PROJECT_ID; //https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents#settings
    const sessionId = 'quickstart-session-id';
    var query = msg;
    const languageCode = 'en-US';

    // Instantiate a DialogFlow client.
    const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');
    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();

    // Define session path
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);

    // The text query request.
    const request = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        text: {
          text: query,
          languageCode: languageCode,
        },
      },
    };

    // Send request and log result
    sessionClient
      .detectIntent(request)
      .then(responses => {
        console.log('Detected intent');
        const result = responses[0].queryResult;
        console.log(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
        console.log(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
        if (result.intent) {
          console.log(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`  No intent matched.`);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
      });
  }
  return;
});
```

That is the relevant part of the code. For those wondering, the `process.env.PROJECT_ID` is something glitch.com uses for anything private. Because I don't want random people getting their hands on my project id, I hide it in there and glitch hides it from anyone I don't explicitly invite.

Every time I execute this and try to query the bot, it returns an error `Uncaught Promise Error:  TypeError: dialogflow.SessionsClient is not a constructor`.

If someone can direct me to what I'm missing, or what the problem is, that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

As per [@google-cloud/dialogflow - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/dialogflow)

> **IMPORTANT NOTE**
> Version 2.0.0 renames dialogflow to @google-cloud/dialogflow on npm, along with introducing TypeScript types.

So to update the dialogflow to use latest version, first uninstall dialogflow and then install with following command:

`npm uninstall dialogflow`

`npm i @google-cloud/dialogflow`

Also, if you were using older version 1.2.0 of dialogflow before then in code, make following changes as per their sample or refer the sample from above link (in require and to get the sessionPath):

```js
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');
const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectAgentSessionPath(
    projectId,
    sessionId
  );
```

It worked fine for me after doing this without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After many many refreshes, I decided to look at the npm documentation for it. Turns out some idiot listed the earliest version as 4.0.3, and the latest version as 0.7.0. I needed to explicitly tell it to use version 0.7.0 in order for it to work. Thank goodness!

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked by reinstalling the dialogflow package

npm uninstall dialogflow

npm install dialogflow --save

Answer (score -2):

put the code inside try and catch block. In my case by doing this, this error was removed.